# Zookeeper install via Ambari

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Performing install via Ambari 1.7 and would like to get some clarification regarding the Zookeeper installation. The setup involves (3) Zookeeper and (3) Kafka instances. 
Ambari UI asks to specify Zookeeper master(s) and Zookeeper clients/slaves. Should I choose all three Zookeeper nodes as masters and install Zookeeper client on each Kafka server?

Zookeeper doesn't have any master node(s) and I am a little confused here with this Ambari master/slave terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper Server is considered a MASTER component in Ambari terminology. Kafka has the requirement that Zookeeper Server be installed on at least one node in the cluster. Thus the only requirement you have is to install Zookeeper server on one of the nodes in your cluster for Kafka to function. Kafka does not require Zookeeper clients on each Kafka node.

You can determine all this information by looking at the Service configurations for KAFKA and ZOOKEEPER. The configuration is specified in the metainfo.xml file for each component under the stack definition. The location of the definitions will differ based on the version of Ambari you have installed.

On newer versions of Ambari this location is:

```
   /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/<service name>/<service version>
```

On older version of Ambari this location is:

```
  /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/<stack version>/services/<service name>
```